# Regex get error in textbox when having space at the end

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the following regex for validation of numbers which is working fine.
Problem is that if you enter in the textbox some valid number and then press *space*, the expression is not valid anymore.
How should I ignore spaces at the end of the entered value by regex handling ?

```
@"^[0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@"^[0-9]+\s*$"
```

like this you can make the space take zero or more spaces at the end.

`*` is a quantifier made for this particular purpose

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. add `\s*` to the regEx - `@"^[0-9]+\s*$"` - it means any number of white
   spaces of any kind are allowed after at least one digit
2. Use the regEx on the trimmed text of the textbox - `regEx.IsMatch(TextBox.Text.Trim())`